# Can't pass pointer to derived class function into base class

Tags: c++, boost, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to pass a function from a derived class to a base class function which expects a function pointer, but I'm getting a compiler error.

```
[BCC32 Error] E2034 Cannot convert 'void (Bar::*)(int)' to 'void (Foo::*)(int)'
```

I guess this is as designed, but is there a way around this that doesn't involve unpleasant casting? Can `boost::bind` help me here?

```
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember))

class Foo
{
public:
  typedef void (Foo::*FFunc)(int i);

  void test(FFunc f)
  {
    CALL_MEMBER_FN(*this,f)(123);
  }

  void barf1(int i) {};
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
  void barf2(int i) {};
};

void ffff()
{
  Foo f;
  f.test(Foo::barf1); // works

  Bar b;
  b.test(Bar::barf1); // works
  b.test(Bar::barf2); // ERROR
}
```

As a side note, I have this working fine using a virtual function, which is the obvious approach rather than a function pointer, but I'm just trying to get it working this way before attempting some boost::bind trickery later...

Comment: If you have a C++11 compiler, maybe you can use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) together with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)?

Answer (score 1):

`b.test( ( Foo::FFunc )&Bar::barf2 );`

Sorry, didn't mean to submit it as answer, wanted to comment. [Sample code](http://ideone.com/TUXbN).

EDIT: Well, maybe this is more "pleasant" casting, since it's C++ style? [Updated sample.](http://ideone.com/OEugf)

`b.test( static_cast< Foo::FFunc >(&Bar::barf2) );`

Comment: Well yes, that works. but that's sort of the "unpleasant casting" I was hoping to avoid!

Comment: @Roddy You can use `static_cast`, that's totally valid C++ cast. I mean, I bet `boost::bind` uses such casting things internally somewhere...

Comment: Are you sure that's valid c++? From what I remember casting a function (or member function) pointer to a different type and then trying to call it is illegal. It might work in this case, since the cast from `b` to `Foo*` (when calling `test`) is probably a noop, but I think that is not guaranteed (and won't work if multiple or virtual inheritance was involved).

Comment: @Grizzly There is no cast from `Bar*` to `Foo*` when calling `test`. `test` is a member of `Bar`...  The thing I called "valid C++ cast" is `static_cast` on functions that have same signature. If you declare `void barf2( float);` compiler won't let you `static_cast` it.

Answer (score 1):

As well, as my knowledge of  c++11 && bost && stl are not the best, I can only advise this:

```
 template <typename T>
    void test(void (T::*f)(int))
  {
    CALL_MEMBER_FN(static_cast<T&>(*this),f)(123);
  }
```

All other code same to yours.

Bad casting, but it is hidden

Answer (score 1):

Can you generalise the function pointer a bit more? I mean something like this:

```
typedef void (Foo::*FFunc)(int i);
```

to:

```
typedef void (*FFunc)(int i);
```

Then you can use bind:

```
b.test(bind(&Bar::barf2, &b));
```

Comment: No you can't since `bind` (I assume you mean `boost::bind` or `std::bind`, otherwise please elaborate) returns a functor object and not a function pointer. `typedef function<void(int)> FFunc;` should work though (but with lots of overhead of course).
`

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I use boost:function, not function pointers. bind won't work with pointer.